# Write integration tests with React using Jest

Tags: testing, integration-tests, reactjs

Let's imagine that we have this **Page** component:

```
const Page = () =>
  <>
    <Topbar />
    <Drawer />
    <Content />
  </>
```

I'd like to test some interaction within the **Drawer** and the **Content** components in an integration test, mounting our **Page** component, so I'd write a mock for the **Topbar** component, because I don't need it, with:

```
jest.mock('./Topbar', () => {
  const TopbarMock = () => null
  return TopbarMock
})
```

Then our tests won't render this component, increasing its execution time and it's less open to fail due to some bug introduced there, isolating our feature.

The problem I have is that, every time I need to add a new component in the **Page** component, I have to do the same I did for the **Topbar**.

My question is if there is any way to specify the components you're going to need for this integration test instead of the ones that you won't need (exactly the other way around). Something like, for this feature that I'm currently testing, I'll just need the **Drawer** and the **Content** components, so don't render anything else.

Or, is there a better way to write integration tests without needing to mock?

Comment: Maybe you have too big components if you feel like you’re cheating too much by being forced to use a mock every time you change Page ?